# PySpark: readStream from local directory gives "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException"

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

With pyspark, I am **trying to stream from a directory, that can contain many CSV files, and post the dataframe to kafka.**
With the `readStream.csv()` I am getting **FileNotFoundException**.
Code is below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("pyspark_stream_setup").getOrCreate()
path = "/home/username/data_dir"
path = "file://"+path
df_schema = StructType() \
            .add("Business_Date","string")\     
            .add("Currency_Code","string")\
            .add("Currency_Name","string")\
            .add("COF","string")


df = spark.readStream.csv(path,sep=sep,schema=df_schema,inferSchema=True,header=True)
df1 = df.withColumn("payload",to_json(struct(*df.columns)))
cols = df.columns
if "key" in cols:
    data_new = df1.select(col("key"),col("payload").alias("value"))
else:
    data_new = df1.withColumn("key",lit("")).select(col("key"),col("payload").alias("value"))
data_new.writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .options(**kafka_config) \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

Error:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]22/06/01 07:30:44 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, my.server.com, executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/username/data_dir/fix_rates.csv does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:624)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]^C2022-06-01 07:30:47,002 - kedro.framework.session.store - INFO - `save()` not implemented for `BaseSessionStore`. Skipping the step.

Aborted!
```

I cannot use `SparkFiles.add()` because it will require file name. But in my case many csv files can keep coming in "data_dir" folder.
As an alternative I thought of creating a pandas dataframe from CSV and converting it to pyspark dataframe using `createDataframe()`, but don't know how to stream a dataframe, something like: `df2 = df.readStream()`
How should i overcome the FileNotFoundException ?

Comment: Hi, if you can not use addfile than only solution i can think of is assigning spark master as "local" instead of "yarn". Driver and all executors will be on same host and all executors can access to source directory.

Comment: @ozlemg client will kill me me if i use "local". As a workaround, I am placing the files on HDFS, and assigning `path = "hdfs:///streaming/dir/path`.

Comment: hdfs makes sense. And of course you are right, local is not a proper production configuration.